# Are there any good-aligned tempest gods with a portfolio focused on lightning?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

Are there any tempest gods that are both good-aligned and focused on lightning/thunder?

It's fine if it's not exact but almost all of the good-aligned tempest gods are more focused on sailing and the sea so it's been really hard to find a god for this archetype.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### In the Forgotten Realms pantheon, no.

None of the gods in the forgotten realms pantheon fit what you are looking for. Finding something closer to what you are after requires drawing from a different pantheon, or stepping into another setting entirely and allowing Neutrally aligned deities.

#### Norse Pantheon: Thor, Chaotic Good

Thor is the god of thunder having a Chaotic Good alignment. It will be up to your DM, but the PHB has the following guidance concerning real-world pantheons:

> The Celtic, Egyptian, Greek, and Norse pantheons are fantasy interpretations of historical religions from our world’s ancient times. They include deities that are most appropriate for use in a D&D game, divorced from their historical context in the real world and united into pantheons that serve the needs of the game.

#### Greek Pantheon: Zeus, True Neutral

After Thor, there is probably not a more iconic lightning god than Zeus slinging thunderbolts down from Olympus. Zeus gives a True Neutral option here.

#### Exandrian and Greyhawk Pantheons: Kord, the Storm Lord, Chaotic Neutral (Good in Greyhawk)

The Storm Lord of Exandria gives an option that is at least not evil.

> Where thunder booms and conflict rises, prayers to the Storm Lord are shouted into the maelstrom. Reveling in all tests of strength, Kord blesses those who prove themselves on the battlefield. Worshiped by athletes and warriors all across Exandria, he exalts those whose force of spirit and desire for victory call his attention. He brings tumultuous storms over land and sea, and those who wish for clearer skies offer their praises and prayers to appease him.

Notably, Kord is also a part of the Greyhawk pantheon where he is considered Chaotic Good, though little details about him are given for that setting as D&D 5e does not have a Greyhawk campaign book yet.

#### Theros Pantheon: Keranos, God of Storms, Chaotic Neutral

Keranos is described:

> Keranos is the god of storms and wisdom. Merciless and impatient, Keranos is equally likely to strike out at mortals with a bolt of inspiration or a blast of lightning. To revere Keranos is to exult in the power of wisdom, clarity of purpose, and the fury of the storm. He is favored by tinkerers, inventors, and sailors as well as those seeking solutions to intractable problems. He doesn’t tolerate the company (or the worship) of fools, and he despises vapidity and indecision.

Comment: There's also Zeus from the Greek Pantheon, who is (true) Neutral.